# What element is being displayed onbeforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, css, alert, prompt, onbeforeunload

I'm using `on('beforeunload')` to trigger a prompt when user tries to close tab with my page. I think it's a system alert and it is [really neat](https://jsfiddle.net/chadwallacehart/zanh6jnv/).

What kind of element is this and is it possible to use this style as an alert or prompt somewhere else within my app? I can't find anything about it. `alert` or `prompt` look totally different.

This is the thing on Safari:

[image: this is the thing]

And that's a "default" alert by Safari as well, it's 10x uglier:

[image: this is an alert]

Comment: This is a built in dialog from the client. The style of these built in dialogs are not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The `prompt` and `alert` dialogues are browser modals. All browser implementations that I can think of do not show the modal within the HTML page, but as a separate GUI dialogue on top of the main window; thus the modal is outside the scope of the document and cannot be targeted by styles.

The HTML living spec at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#simple-dialogs only states that, when invoking a `prompt` or `alert`, the message should be configurable. If any browser implemented the ability to configure styling for alert modals, this would be beyond the spec and a non standard feature.

In short: the spec does not include style configurations for dialogues and no browser vendors have implemented it.

---

Perhaps you could make a fixed element within the page, on top of all other elements, with the required styling, and use a function to show/hide that instead of the built in `alert()`.

```
function alert2( msg ) {
    const modal = document.getElementById( 'modal' )
    modal.innerHTML = typeof msg === 'string' ? msg : 'Alert!!'
    modal.style.display = 'block'
}

...

alert2( 'This is an alert' )
```